# AS2 Parent - Child swf communication

Tags: flash, query-string, swfobject

How do I do this?

**Inside the parent swf**

myVar value is set by query string value loaded in by swfobject

```
var myVar = _level0.part; // i have the value 123 here ..all good so far


loadMovieNum("childa.swf", 3);
```

**Inside the child swf**

```
var principal = MovieClip(parent.root);

childLog.text = principal.myVar;
```

or

```
childLog.text = root.loaderInfo.parameters["part"];
```

or

```
childLog.text = _parent._levell0.part;
```

Always childLog.text is undefined :( - so how to access the value of **myvar** from the child?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually more simple than your examples:

```
childLog.text = _level0.myVar;
```